# Deserialize a java class after changing the original class methods

Tags: java, serialization

I have a java class in file AJavaClass.java in a project say MyFirstProject

```
package mypackage;

class AJavaClass implements java.io.Serializable{
      //instance variables
      int var1;
      int var2;
      String stringVar1;
      AJavaClass(arg1,arg2){
           aJavaClassMethod(arg1,arg2);
      }
      public void aJavaClassMethod(arg1,arg2){
      }

}
```

In another project, say MySecondProject, I have the same class and under same named package in that project, but with a slightly different structure:

```
package mypackage;
class AJavaClass java.io.Serializable{
      //instance variables
      int var1;
      int var2;
      String stringVar1;
      //note 4 param constructor
      AJavaClass(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){
           aJavaClassMethod(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4);
      }
      //note 4 param method but with same name
      public void aJavaClassMethod(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){
      }

}
```

Now I created MyFirstProject earlier than MySecondProject. Then I serialized several instances of AJavaClass into a directory. 
But later on, due to some very genuine reasons, I needed to update the AJavaClass so that the aJavaClassMethod takes in 4 params.Now the problem is that when I try to deserialize the Objects serialized by  MySecondProject's AJavaClass using MyFirstProject's AJavaClass, it is giving me `java.io.InvalidClassException:`

So is there any way that I can use the objects serialized by the MySecondProject's AJavaClass in the MyFirstProject?(Please note there is no zero-arg constructor in the class, so inheritance is ruled out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way that I can use the objects serialized by the MySecondProject's AJavaClass in the MyFirstProject?

Yes. The exception message tells you the actual and expected serialVersionUID` values. Just put the expected value into the new version of the class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789L;  // or whatever the message says
```

In fact, put it into the old version as well if it is still extant.

Comment: Sorry for marking so late.It worked as expected.Thank you very much!!

Answer (score -1):

Unless you revert to the class structure that existed when the serialized data was written you will not be able to get the data back. If no `serialVersionUID` is defined then Java generates one based on the class structure. If the serial ID of the class is different from that of the file, you will get a `InvalidClassException`.

If the data is crucial, revert the class and grab the data. If you really wanted you could have both versions of the class and write a method to load the files, create an instance of the latest class and write it back over the data.

Comment: Untrue and unnecessary.